# How are threads managed in the new C++17 parallel algorithms?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, std

Is there a good reference on how the new C++17 parallel algorithms manage their threads? Aka when and how many threads are created? Are they created/ destroyed for each call?

I presume the answer depends on the used compiler. So I would be particularly interested in the gcc implmentation of it.

Comment: libstdc++ was offered Intel's implementation, but don't know what the status of that is right now.

Comment: It cant be fixed how many threads are created, it should at least depend on std::hardware_concurrency(), which returns the actual numbers of hw threads you can use. But yes, they are created and destroyed on each call.

Answer (score 1):

GCC implements C++17 parallel algorithms via Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB) library: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/05/09/cpp-17-stl-parallel-algorithms-gcc-intel-tbb-linux-macos/

TBB maintains a pool of threads not to recreate them each time. This can be verified using this simple program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "new thread\n"; }
};
thread_local A a;

int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 100000;
    std::vector<int> v(N);
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
       v[i] = N - i;
    auto v1 = v, v2 = v;

    auto comparator = [](int l, int r) {
        (void)a; // to create thread_local object in new thread
        return l < r;
    };
 
    std::cout << "Hardware concurrency: " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << "\n";
    std::cout << "First parallel algorithm:\n";
    std::sort( std::execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), comparator );
    std::cout << "Second parallel algorithm:\n";
    std::sort( std::execution::par_unseq, v1.begin(), v1.end(), comparator );
    std::cout << "Third parallel algorithm:\n";
    std::sort( std::execution::par_unseq, v2.begin(), v2.end(), comparator );
}
```

which prints `new thread` each time the comparator is called from yet another thread.

On my computer with AMD Ryzon 9 3900X processor, Ubuntu 20.04 and GCC 10.3 it prints:

```
$ /usr/bin/g++-10 -std=c++20 par.cpp -ltbb
$ ./a.out
Hardware concurrency: 24
First parallel algorithm:
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
new thread
Second parallel algorithm:
new thread
new thread
Third parallel algorithm:
```

meaning that after all 24 threads are created, they keep being reused in the following parallel algorithms.